# Bash - reuse the output in pipes if the first consumer fails

Tags: bash, pipe, skip, error-code, return-code

I have an expensive operation (`curl`call). This may or may not produce JSON. If it does, I want to pretty print it using `json_pp`. But if that fails, I want to print it as-is.

This is what I have now:

```
filter "$ENVI" "$2" running | dns_ \
   | xargs  -L1 --max-args=1 -I{} $DEBUG_XARGS --no-run-if-empty \
   sh -c "echo 'Versions at {}': ; curl --fail http://... | json_pp"
```

The relevant part is

```
curl --fail http://... | json_pp
```

When the output is JSON, it's ok. But when it's not, I get:

> malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "Version: 18.4.0, bui...") at /usr/bin/json_pp line 45.

I would like to somehow react to the error code of `json_pp`, so that if it is not `0`, the output would be passed further in the pipe (where `cat` would take it), but if it returned `0` (accepted the JSON), the pipe would not continue (or continue with `json_pp`'s output).

**In other words, I want to skip the step in the pipe which fails.**
How can I achieve this? Looking for something like

```
curl --fail http://... | ifTheFollowingFailsThenPassAsIsOtherwiseUseOutputOf json_pp | cat
```

Because it all happens in `xargs`, I am looking for a short solution, something like [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html). It may be a Bash function, too.

Comment: Using `tee` can help for funneling effect: `.... | tee | json_pp` (Not tried!)

Comment: @Cryptopat, that doesn't do what the OP wants here, which is to have *either* processed output or original input, but not both.

Comment: I figured I could use `tee` and `||`:  `curl ... | tee file | json_pp || cat file`. Going to try.

Comment: @OndraŽižka, using `tee` may work with today's version of json_pp, but it isn't guaranteed to continue to work in the future (if the program is enhanced to use a streaming parser, in which case it could emit some stdout *before* finding a place where it can't parse further input).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I figured out a while after posting:

```
bbTmp=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/bbPp.XXXXXX")
export bbTmp # to be available to sh -c

filter "$ENVI" "$2" running | dns_ | xargs  -L1 --max-args=1 -I{} --no-run-if-empty \
  sh -c 'curl --fail http://{}/... | tee "$bbTmp" | json_pp 2>/dev/null || cat "$bbTmp"'
```

This works just as I need. Thanks for the other tips, will be useful for more generic solutions.

Comment: Err. Do you have a {} inside the `...` part of your `sh -c` command? It's very much safer to pass arguments as external arguments rather than relying on replacement inside the shell command's source code -- in the latter case, if your text being replaced by xargs contains something like `$(foo)`, that can be run as a command. So `xargs ... sh -c '...' _` is safer, such that your `...` can then refer to `"$1"` for the argument from `xargs` rather than having it substituted into (and parsed as) code.

Comment: Yep, `{}` is the hostname. Edited. I don't get the `_` part. Can you please give a link to what that is? I see something about `xargs -e` in it's man page, but not sure how that works here.

Comment: `_` is a placeholder for `$0` -- it's not anything to do with xargs, but to do with `bash -c`, since the first argument after the script is `$0`, the second one is `$1`, etc. Filling it in means that the argument after that becomes `$1`.

Comment: so, `http://{}/...` is dangerous because if someone manages to slip `$(rm -rf ~)` into your list of hostnames, then your code will delete a bunch of files. Consequently, it's safer to make it `"http://$1/..."` inside the `bash -c '...'` string, and pass the `{}` out-of-band, after the `_`.

Comment: In [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), search for "*Don't ever put `{}` directly inside a mini-script being executed by `bash -c` or `sh -c`!*".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50046513/7 in history showing how I'd write this to avoid that; backed it out since it's a significant enough change that persisting it calls for your consent. (If the output of `dns_` is line-oriented, I'd also add `-d $'\n'` to the list of arguments to `xargs`).

Comment: I see `for arg do`; but where does the `{}` go?

Comment: Oh wait. `xargs` passes that as an argument to the command I give it, after `_`. The `_` is there because the command doesn't create the 0th argument as normal when calling a script. I start getting it. It's a bit complicated. But the resulting script saves me a ton of time so it's worth doing it right.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, are you interested in seeing the whole script at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? I have stuffed it with a lot of things I found around the web, and I bet it is full of security traps. At the other hand it's quite interesting code golf.

Answer (score 2):

```
tryOrCat() {
  local input output
  input=$(cat) || return
  if output=$("$@" <<<"$input"); then
    printf '%s\n' "$output"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$input"
  fi
}
```

...thereafter:

```
whatever | tryOrCat json_pp
```

Comment: To hide any error messages add `2>/dev/null` inside the second `$(...)`.

Comment: Yup. I'd rather put the onus on the user to hide errors by doing that redirection themselves; that way they have control of whether or not they want access for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Output in a pipeline can only be processed once. You'll need to either duplicate it or save it. The latter is easy:

```
json=$(curl --fail http://...)
json_pp <<< "$json" || printf '%s\n' "$json"
```

This will leave `json_pp`'s error message visible. If you want to hide it you can redirect stderr:

```
json_pp <<< "$json" 2>/dev/null || printf '%s\n' "$json"
```

Comment: `json_pp` can both emit (partial) output *and* a nonzero exit status, so this could result in partial output (from `json_pp`, prior to the point where it fails) being concatenated with full input (from the `printf`).

Comment: ...granted, [the current implementation of `json_pp`](https://github.com/deftek/json_pp/blob/ea18f5b2aef90812d92e1d94ec9dc8ea0a283ab3/bin/json_pp#L70) appears to do a full parse before it writes any output at all, but a streaming implementation of this tool -- where it's doing both parsing and generation incrementally in-line -- is definitely possible, and is an enhancement that -- as it would result in bounded memory usage -- is perhaps even *likely* to happen at some point in the future.